# how and where to include js and css for modules?

Tags: php, yii, yii-modules

I have modules for category:

```
+modules/
 +category/
    +assets/
      +css/
      +js/
      +images/
    +components/
    +controllers/
    +models/
    +views/
    -CategoryModule.php
```

What is the best way to includes the css and jss to all views?

Comment: create the header page and call it in all pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publish and register in `CategoryModule` `init` method - this will make available your css and js in category module.
Something like this:

```
public function  init() {
    $path = $this->assetManager->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.modules.category.assets'));
    $this->clientScript->registerCssFile($path . '/css/some-css.css', 'screen, projection');
    $this->clientScript->registerScriptFile($path . '/js/some-js.js');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create module layout file under views/layout and call it in module config file as

```
$this->layoutPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.modules.moduleName.views.layouts');
        $this->layout = '/layouts/layoutname';
```

register all the js and css file as @PeterM mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder "layouts" in your views folder. Create main.php in that layouts folder.

In your , add following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/cycle.js"></script>
```

This is your default layout. So add,

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

This is another method to include css and js in all views.

Comment: what is the $content and where should I add this.

Comment: Add $content in your main.php only. When you use layout view like layout/main.php or layout/column1.php etc the $content variable contains the view content (controller/action render) and then passing into the layout.

Answer (score -1):

Easy using this static method

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.modules.curriculo.assets') . '/bootstrap/datepicker/css/datepicker.css'); ?>
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.modules.curriculo.assets') . '/bootstrap/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

This should help you:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/

All three sections (beginContent, container and endContent) are explained in detail.